# Issue in handling async function called by another function

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, async-await

Briefly , I have 2 functions A,B

A is async function , takes time to request something then be ready with response to return

B take output from A

here's my codes

```
async function A()
{
    axios.get('API_ENDPOINT_URL').then(async function (rates) {
        return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
            resolve(rates.data.data);
        });
    });
}

async function B(id)
{
    var results = A();
    console.log(results); // this output Promise { undefined }
}
```

how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var results = await A();
```

just await the execution of A. And also fix A itself, it is completely missusing promises:

```
 async function A() {
  const rates = await axios.get('API_ENDPOINT_URL')
  return  rates.data.data;
}
```

Comment: without await , it output Promise { undefined }

with await , it output undefined

Comment: @27mdmo7sn  So that would imply,  `rates.data.data` is undefined, did you mean to do `rates.data` ?

Comment: @keith maybe that or its just because he commented before my edit, and still refers to his code which doesnt return anything from A

Comment: Yes @JonasWilms , You're right
your answer worked with me , it is more simple/easy without using promises

Comment: I mean it's simple without declaring a new Promise and return reject or resolve , that's was a bit not easy

Answer (score 0):

Your function A returns a promise, so you can either use 
`await A()` or `A().then(results => console.log(results))`

Answer (score 0):

You have call .then on a promise, like this:

```js
function A()
{
  return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
      resolve("test");
  });
}

function B()
{
  A().then(result=>console.log(result));
}

B();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no particular reason you need `async` or `await` here.  You can also just return a value from the `.then()` handler which will work in any environment that supports axios (doesn't require async/await support):

```
function A() {
    return axios.get('API_ENDPOINT_URL').then(function (rates) {
        return rates.data.data;
    });
}

// usage
A().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

In case you didn't realize, both this version and the version above using `await` return the same thing - a promise that resolves to `rates.data.data` or rejects with an axios error.

Returning a value from a `.then()` handler changes the resolved value of the promise chain to the value you returned.

Unless that value is also a promise in which case that promise gets added to the chain and the resolved value of the chain becomes the resolved value of that new promise that you returned.